# Computer crashed, how to copy my whole drive?

Tags: bsod, ms-dos

I got a BSOD on my Windows7 laptop.  No options to boot in safe mode and a newbie.  How do I copy my whole drive to an external hdd in MSDOS

I have attempted xcopy D:\*.* G:\ /s.  thinking that this should copy everything in my D: drive to the G: (my external hdd) drive.

However, it keeps stalling at the same point about 1hr into it.

Comment: if you have iso-file of ubuntu then you can backup your date after opening computer with live-tool through usb

Comment: No I don't.  :(.

Comment: you could still use a window live cd, but to answer for msdos, Copy may bludgeon your long filenames > 8.3 length though there are workarounds to copy in dos and preserve long filenames(you have to download a few extra little commands to your boot disk/"boot disk" to do that).  really you should look to downloading a live cd, or moving the drive to another computer and copying from windows.

Comment: not msdos but does this help? it might help you make a cd and boot off it and do a copy from a gui, maybe. it may have something.  http://www.hirensbootcd.org/files/Hirens.BootCD.15.2.zip

Comment: My laptop doesn't have cd drive, and I don't have another computer to dld the files anyway.  Was just going to do it the long way and backup the drive to ext hdd.  Just not sure why MSDOS isn't copying my whole drive across - is it to do with long names?

Comment: MS-DOS has no built-in commands to copy an entire drive. Working around that would be challenging to an expert. Boot into a suitable OS. The Windows 7 installer is likely to be capable of fixing your problem.

Comment: Where are you posting from? Can't you access another PC temporarily to download and burn a copy of Linux or create a LiveUSB?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/C` to your command:
`/C`           Continues copying even if errors occur.